# How to change a binary KNN classifier to be a SVM classifier?

Tags: matlab

I am classifying gender using a KNN classifier. 
I want to add an SVM classifier instead of KNN classifier with the same labels of 0 and 1 (0 for women and 1 for men)

I have a matrix of test examples, `sample`, a matrix of training examples, `training`, and a vector with the labels for the training examples `group`. I want `class`, a vector of the labels for the test examples.

```
class = knnclassify(sample, training, group);
if class==1
    x='Male';
else
    x='Female';
end
```

How can I change this code to find `class` using an SVM?

Comment: Can you describe the error or the undesired output that you are getting? One possible problem, this code has an unmatched 'end' in the third line.

Comment: the end belong to unseen code ..the undesired output is that the code classify the gender by knn only but it does not classify the gender by svm  ...any help??

Comment: You use the `knnclassify` function which does a k-nearest neighbor classification. If you want to use a SVM classifier, you need to use `fitcsvm` and `predict` to train your SVM and classify your data. [This tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-for-binary-classification.html#bss0s6_-1) should help

Comment: Your code snippet is confusing because it does not provide example input and output, and it is not valid code. I appreciate that you trimmed your code to highlight the relevant portions, but it is preferred if you can provide a true [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sample= coefficent';
         training=X ;
        group = Y;
        class = knnclassify(sample, training, group);
      this is the main part to me ..but  does the svm-fitcsvm work with the labels of 0 and 1 as the knn do for male and female?

Comment: In the tutorial that I linked, they use labels {-1, 1}, but {0, 1} should also work.

Comment: I've edited your question to use the simpler code and have a more clear problem statement.

Comment: thank you very much Cecilia ...

Comment: can you help me to write the classification part in RBF -svm instead of KNN classifier?

Comment: My answer below is most of what you need. You just have to add a RBF kernel. The second example in the [fitcsvm documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html#bt8x_mu-1) does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

To train an SVM, you will need the [Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html).

The biggest difference between the [`knnclassify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html) and using an SVM classifier is that training and classifying new labels will be two separate steps.

### 1. Train your SVM : [`fitcsvm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html)

This step teaches the classifier how to distinguish between your two classes. It is learning a linear separator (or a weighted combination of the features) which has the largest margin between positive and negative examples. All the examples you give it need to have ground truth labels.

SVM's have many tunable parameters that you can adjust during the training step. There are several good [tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-for-binary-classification.html#bss0s6_-1) in the Matlab documentation which describe the differences, but for the most basic version, you can just use your training examples

```
model = fitcsvm(training,group);
```

This model will be used in the next step.

### 2. Classify new examples : [`predict`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm.predict.html)

To classify your new example, run

```
class = predict(sample, model);
```

### Notes:

Using your model, you can also run cross-fold validation, useful for accuracy analysis.

```
cvModel = crossval(model);
classError = kfoldLoss(cvModel);
```

You can also save your model, like any other Matlab variable for future use.

```
save('model.m', 'model');
```

`knnclassify` comes from the bioinformatics toolbox. In the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, there is also a KNN model which you train with [`fitcknn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcknn.html) and classify with [`predict`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationknn.predict.html). The benefit is that you can reuse your KNN model with several sets of data, compare cross-validation results, and save it for future use.